# How to authenticate using JWT in reactjs stored in localstorage on refresh page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt

i have stored my user login status in state. when i refresh my page, state initialized and jwt token is in localstorage.now, my application shows user not logged in but, when make a request it gets jwt token from localstorage and complete the protected requests.

i want to update my state when i refresh the page. let know the solution.
my entire project -https://codesandbox.io/s/react-library-fe-7p8rf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you didn't store the userData like you did for jwt, this is why `if (user.isLoggedIn) {` in your `UserComponent` will always give you false after refresh, try setting user data to localstorage in your `Login` component

```
localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(res.user));
```

And in your userContext update your initialState:

```
const initialState = {
   isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem("jwt") ? true : false,
   userData: localStorage.getItem("currentUser")
       ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"))
       : "undefined"
};
```

You can try to parse the jwt token too to extract user data (data will might be not the same userData object you want):

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
const userData = JSON.parse(atob(token.split(".")[1]));
```

Even with all this you should create a webservice to validate/refresh your jwt, because once your token is expired you cannot get any response from any webservice.

Comment: i like do so. but i am stater in stack overflow hence my vote not considered

Comment: I think you can now https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question here's what i did,

1. I created a route in my api sever which validates the token and returns the user object eg: `/auth/validate`
2. I created an action named validateToken in  my react app, in that route I am get the token from localstorage and send it to sever `/auth/validate` and storing the returned user from server in my state.
3. In App component i am calling that function in `useEffect()` of `componentDidMount()`

Thus once the page is reloaded the app will then send the request to server with the jwt token from localstorage and server returns user object.
You can also show the loader while it's sending the request :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your state this way when the user refreshed the page:

```js
// UserContext.js

case "SET_USER":
      return { ...state, isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem("jwt") ? true : false };
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the login credential in `useEffect` and set the `loginUser` data to your state:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   let loginUser= window.localStorage.setItem("jwt", res.jwt);
});
```